# multiple inner join together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following inner joins:

V1:

```
select distinct f.ci_frec, v.codfs_venta, v.codbeb_venta
from frecuenta f inner join vende v on (codfs_frec = codfs_venta)
```

V2:

```
select distinct g.ci_gusta, v.codfs_venta, g.codbeb_gusta
from vende v inner join gusta g on (codbeb_venta = codbeb_gusta)
```

Now, I want V3 = V1 - V2, which is why I've used an EXCEPT statement as follows:

```
select distinct f.ci_frec, v.codfs_venta, v.codbeb_venta
from frecuenta f inner join vende v on (codfs_frec = codfs_venta)
EXCEPT
select distinct g.ci_gusta, v.codfs_venta, g.codbeb_gusta
from vende v inner join gusta g on (codbeb_venta = codbeb_gusta)
```

So far everything works as expected. My issue now comes that I want to have V4 resulting from having an inner join between V3 and V1, however I do not know how I can make this. Is there a way I can name the inner joins I've already made to do something such as

```
select *
from V3 inner join V1 on (V3.codbeb_gusta = V1.codbeb_gusta)
```

or do I need to use a lot of parenthesis and build some sort of "outer" inner join with the two original inner joins V1 and V2 inside it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "V4 = V3 inner join V1" <-- what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Dai I want to create a new inner join (V4) joining the two previous table I got (V1 and V3). The names are just for not getting lost since before doing this in sql I made it on relational algebra

Comment: SQL is based on relational-calculus, not relational-algebra.

Comment: @Dai Ive been learning databases for only about a week, and haven't gotten to the topic of relational calculus yet. What I want to do right now is see if I can make the inner join as I asked above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WITH`. You can read about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

```
WITH V1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT f.ci_frec, v.codfs_venta, v.codbeb_venta
    FROM frecuenta f INNER JOIN vende v on (codfs_frec = codfs_venta)
), V2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT g.ci_gusta, v.codfs_venta, g.codbeb_gusta
    FROM vende v INNER JOIN gusta g on (codbeb_venta = codbeb_gusta)
), V3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM V1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM V2
)
SELECT *
FROM V3
INNER JOIN V1 on (V3.codbeb_gusta = V1.codbeb_gusta)
```